# Python tkinter bind hover and keypress

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, bind

I have a tkinter canvas window and trying to use the method tag_bind to bind a combination of events, mouse over and pressing a specific letter.

What I have tried is:

```
    self.element_block = self.canvas.create_window( (0, 0), window=self.block_main, anchor="nw", width=self.block_width, height=self.block_height )
    self.canvas.tag_bind( self.element_block, '<Enter><p>', self.parameter_window_operator )

    self.element_block = self.canvas.create_window( (0, 0), window=self.block_main, anchor="nw", width=self.block_width, height=self.block_height )
    self.canvas.tag_bind( self.element_block, '<Enter> <p>', self.parameter_window_operator ) 

    self.element_block = self.canvas.create_window( (0, 0), window=self.block_main, anchor="nw", width=self.block_width, height=self.block_height )
    self.canvas.tag_bind( self.element_block, '<Enter p>', self.parameter_window_operator ) 

    self.element_block = self.canvas.create_window( (0, 0), window=self.block_main, anchor="nw", width=self.block_width, height=self.block_height )
    self.canvas.tag_bind( self.element_block, '<Enter-p>', self.parameter_window_operator ) 

    self.element_block = self.canvas.create_window( (0, 0), window=self.block_main, anchor="nw", width=self.block_width, height=self.block_height )
    self.canvas.tag_bind( self.element_block, '<Enter+p>', self.parameter_window_operator )
```

None of the above methods provide the result that I am seeking, initiating a callback method when a mouse is hovering over a canvas window and a alpha key is pressed.

Your assistance is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I do not think you can bind hover. You can bind entering and exiting so you may be able to build a function that checks how long you have been inside as well as the location of the cursor to determine if you are hovering .

Comment: instead of hover maybe you can try the `'<Enter>'` and `'<Leave>'` bindings to the function

Comment: My language said hover and my examples use '<Enter>', semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't even worry about `tag_bind` for this. You can move too fast for events to register. I know cause, that was my first solution for you and even though it worked fine if you use the mouse normally, it was breakable if you didn't. Try the below method, instead.

Basically `HoverPool` has the canvas constantly checking what is under the mouse. If it is something in the "hoverpool" that something gets it's `focus_set()` triggered, which allows it's key-bindings to work.

```
import tkinter as tk


class HoverPool:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.hoverpool = dict()
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.check)
        
    def addWidget(self, target, tag, pos, **kwargs):
        self.hoverpool[tag] = target
        win   = self.canvas.create_window(pos, window=target, **kwargs)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(win, tag=(tag))

    def check(self, event):
        if len(self.canvas.gettags('current')):
            for k, v in self.hoverpool.items():
                if k in self.canvas.gettags('current'):
                    v.focus_set()
                    return
                    
        self.canvas.master.focus_set()


class App(tk.Tk):
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE = 800, 600, 'Application'

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background='red')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
        
        #init hoverpool
        hoverpool = HoverPool(self.canvas)
                 
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self, background='green', height=50, width=50)
        self.frame1.bind('<Key-p>', self.onFrame1Action)
        self.frame1.bind('<Key-b>', self.onFrame1Action)
        
        #add frame1 to the hover pool
        hoverpool.addWidget(self.frame1, 'frame1', (50,50), anchor='nw')
        
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self, background='green', height=50, width=50)
        self.frame2.bind('<Key-p>', self.onFrame2Action)
        self.frame2.bind('<Key-b>', self.onFrame2Action)
        
        #add frame2 to the hover pool
        hoverpool.addWidget(self.frame2, 'frame2', (105,50), anchor='nw')
        
    def onFrame1Action(self, event):
        if event.char == 'p':
            self.frame1['background'] = 'purple' 
        if event.char == 'b':
            self.frame1['background'] = 'black'
           
    def onFrame2Action(self, event):
        if event.char == 'p':
            self.frame2['background'] = 'pink' 
        if event.char == 'b':
            self.frame2['background'] = 'blue' 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: First, I've pasted your code into my IDE and observed that it works. Second, I've folded your code into mine and it doesn't work. My hunch is that I don't have a plain vanilla frame, I actually have many things packed into that frame. My fear is thus, that the mouse is not technically directly underneath the "main" frame. Ideally, I do not want to bind each thing inside the "main" frame.

Comment: I added some print statements to the code that you provided (that I folded into my side) to test my hypothesis about having things stacked on top/inside of the "main" frame. Turns out, it seems to be a valid thought. Only when I'm at the very edge of the "main" frame does key press binding actually work. Question is then, what are my options?

Comment: Can you turn your "main" frame into a canvas? If so, do that and dump it in `HoverPool`. It would help if you would have posted your code. I only have the tiny information you provided to work with. There's a chance you are going about this entirely wrong.

Comment: Regarding - Ideally I don't want to bind everything in the main frame -- You will have to do that no matter how you do this. You can't "hover" things that your app was never told to "hover". However, you could bind it all in a loop with `mainframe.winfo_children()`

Comment: Some good replies, thank you. I didn't post my code because the issue is occurring deep inside the source code of a GUI which is built up of a forest of classes...isolating the code beyond what I did share would be probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Well, if you ever decide to make a simple mock example and edit your question appropriately I will write a working example for it.